# Calling shuffle function in C# creates an overload error message

Tags: c#, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle my deck and VS says 'no overload for method getRandomized takes 1 arguments'.  I think I'm calling it correctly but clearly there's some syntax that's incorrect.  Can anyone help me make this work?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAYth.png)

Comment: if it is a method of `Deck` why does it need a `Deck` instance passed to it?  In the future please do not post code or error messages as pictures.  Please see [Ask], the [FAQ] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Can you post the beginning of the `getRandomized` method?

Comment: Please don't post images of your code unless you also include the text in the question itself. We can answer you much better if we can directly edit your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use just,

```
dealerDeck.getRandomized();
```